# MS Office 365 Word make excess blocks in RTF

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, rtf

I create and edit 2 RTF files. In each of them I write the word "test", then I make the font in bold (first "te", then "st" in two steps)

1. Open Office Writer

result rtf blocks:

```
{
    \b\ab\rtlch \ltrch\loch\lang1033 test
}
```

size: 2 KiB

text: **test**

---

2. MS Office 365 Word

result rtf blocks:

```
{
    \rtlch\fcs1 \af31507 \ltrch\fcs0
    \b\lang1033\langfe2052\langnp1033\insrsid7543533\charrsid16743564
    \hich\af31506\dbch\af31505\loch\f31506 te
    \hich\af31506\dbch\af31505\loch\f31506 st
}
```

size: 42 KiB

text: **test**

(he make doubled "\hich\af31506\dbch\af31505\loch\f31506" section with the same format. WHY???)

---

Tell me, what is the reason for such redundancy in MS Word?
Is it possible to optimally export an RTF file through Word?

---

**UPD** (solution **@[harrymc](https://superuser.com/users/8672/harrymc)**):

3. Wordpad

I copy text from MS Word to Wordpad and get the most compact RTF:

result rtf blocks: without dublication
size: **255 bytes**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTF was intended to be a document interchange format, not a permanent
storage format.
The reason it's so big is that everything is in ASCII, all formatting is done 
with tags etc. It was intended to be easy for any program to parse,
for import and output, not for word processing.

It's perhaps not the best choice of formats to actually use,
When converting to any "binary" format such as Word's `.docx`,
the size will likely shrink drastically.

A way to reduce the size of an RTF document is to copy-paste the text
from Word into Wordpad, then save it from Wordpad.
The format of the saved file will be simpler and smaller.

Comment: Thanks! I like your suggestion. I'll wait for other answers.